# What is the motivation for Go lang syntax?

Tags: language-design, go

Since the Go lang is getting popular, I started to play with it. I do derive from Java language so when I saw the Go syntax it has been a bit strange to me.

sample code from [go lang project site](https://golang.org/):

```
func NewField(w, h int) *Field {
    s := make([][]bool, h)
    for i := range s {
        s[i] = make([]bool, w)
    }
    return &Field{s: s, w: w, h: h}
}
```

1. Function return type comes after the name, just like in TypeScript.
2. Additional new variable declaration operator consist of `:=` plus regular `=` assignment operator.
3. Reference and pointers usage.
4. At first sight, strange return statement.
5. Method names are starting capitalized, ex.: `a.Set(rand.Intn(w), rand.Intn(h), true)`, and so on.

I know that google team based on C syntax. Yet Java is also C/C++ based and at first impression it seems more readable.

Obviously, after some time, we could used to it, yet I would expect from new language to be even more readable than for example Java.

Therefore my question, what was the motivation behind implementation of the syntax in that one of the 'newest' languages?

Why it seems less readable than more mature languages?

Comment: `:=` is not assignment, it declares a new variable. Assignment is `=`, just like in C.

Comment: At a glance I see little difference between pointer syntax in C and in go (except it uses consistent prefix syntax for types, hardly a surprising change, considering how horrible the C syntax is in that area). And the return looks exactly like in java or C too.

Comment: I cannot agree that return statement looks exactly the same as in Java, except the `return` word itself. In Java curly braces are used to initialize an array, eventually. In the sample above its been used to initialize, well, what? I believe some kind of new Field object. Additionally, for sure there are differences in the pointer syntax, etc. Nobody said it is same. Yet this is not the main subject of the question.

Comment: also no semi colons

Comment: What *is* the main subject of your question?  Can you make your question more specific?  Otherwise, there is a wealth of information already available on the internet that describes the Go designers' motivations in great detail, including [this one](https://talks.golang.org/2015/gophercon-goevolution.slide#1) and [many others](https://www.google.com/search?q=history%20of%20go%20Language).  See also https://golang.org/doc/faq

Comment: @RobertHarvey, added second, more precise question. What I mean is that  Java/Python/Ruby are here for more than 20 years, C/C++ for around 40 years - and they seems to be even more readable than Go, which according do Wikipedia was released on 2009. So once again, beside of the advantages of Go, I would expect it to be even more readable than older languages.

Comment: Well, it's based on C syntax, because that's what everyone knows.  I wouldn't expect a dramatic increase in readability from C syntax if C syntax is the starting point.  If you find it less readable, that's only because you're not familiar with it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, thank you for the links provided, they are helpful. Get your point about C, but even tough Java is C syntax based and its syntax is more friendly - so it is not completely true that we cannot expect a dramatic increase in readability if language syntax is C based.

Comment: Look at the slideshow I linked.  As I understand it (greatly oversimplifying), Go is Pascal/Oberon semantics with C syntax, so syntax is not the only consideration.  Like all things in computing, Go is an exercise in tradeoffs.  I personally find Java's syntax rather elegant (for a curly brace language), but it's a rather awful language in other ways.

Comment: Syntax readability is mainly familiarity. If you learned Java before Go, it would make sense that the Java syntax is more readable to you. That said, the complexity of a language grammar does indicate the difficulty of learning the grammar.

Comment: "Java is also C/C++ based and at first impression it seems more readable." – How did you come to that conclusion? Are you 100% sure that you accounted for all other possible effects, such as familiarity, in your study? Are you 100% sure that the subjects in your study had the same amount of experience in Java and Go, have written the same amount of code in Java and Go, have read the same amount of code in Java and Go, have learnt both and Java and Go to the same depth, and so on?

Comment: @JörgWMittag, that way I would not ask it here, I believe.

Answer (score 7):

Going from Java to Go is strange if you expect it to only be different from Java the way C# is different from Java. That is, not at all. Let Python, Lisp, Closure, or, gasp, PERL break your brain before you proclaim Go to be "a bit strange".

I'm going to tackle these in reverse order so I can save the best for last.

> 5 Method names are starting capitalized, ex.: a.Set(rand.Intn(w), rand.Intn(h), true), and so on.

That's a style from c#. Yawn.

> 4 At first sight, strange return statement.

That's not a strange Go return statement.

```
func vals() (int, int) {
    return 3, 7
}
```

That's [a strange Go return statement](https://gobyexample.com/multiple-return-values).

> 3 Reference and pointers usage.

Oh yeah, I remember those. C++ rides again.

> 2 Additional new variable declaration operator consist of := plus regular = assignment operator.

They gave us `const` and we ignored it. We're getting what we deserve.

> 1 Function return type comes after the name, just like in TypeScript.

Thank god. There's a reason for that.

Any decent user interface designer will tell you the important stuff goes in the upper left corner (so long as you read left to right, top to bottom). It certainly doesn't belong in the middle of a pile of text. So where did we put the function name?

```
/**
 * Well gee I guess you like it when looking for the name of your function 
 * is a fun visual exercise like where's waldo.
 *
 * @returns what you'd expect something named Pi to return but since 
 * we're "professionals" I thought I'd tell you again because duplicate
 * documentation never hurt anyone. 
 */
public double Pi() {
    double result;
    result = CalculatePiUsingRandom(x->Random.getdouble(x));  
    return result;
}
```

Compare with:

```
func pi() double {
   '''Yeah I know triple quote comments are a python thing but you get my point'''
}
```

I'm in favor of anything that moves the function name back to the upper left corner where it belongs.  Sorry if doing what makes sense seems a bit strange.

Comment: The languages you have mentioned are mature. And yes, Perl can be tricky, nevertheless that is also mature language in comparision to Go. The return statement you have mentioned is indeed not usual (2 vals returned), but it is readable (which I kindly remind you, is the main subject here).

Comment: I agree with **most** of this answer.  However, I find a lot of weird inconsistencies in Go syntax.  For example, in your `vals()` function, why does it declare the multiple return types **inside required parentheses**, while the `return` statement **cannot use parentheses**?  Why is a trailing comma in a struct **required** if there is a newline before the closing brace, but **prohibited** if there is not a newline?   (from what I can tell, I'm very beginner)

Comment: @candied_orange, Let me know the motivation behind `for` loop syntax